# Join two data frame by considering if values of paired columns are in range of the value of paired columns in the other dataframe

Tags: r, join, merge

So let me provide some example to explain my question. I have two data df1 and df2. I want to left join two dataset. by satisfying two conditions.

(1) week are identical
(2) m1 and m2 in df1 are same as m1 and m2 in df2 but ignoring the column name

So the expect output is df3

```
 df1<-data.frame("m1"=c("100010","100010","100010","100020","100020","100020"),"m2"=c("100020","100020","100020","100010","100010","100010"),"week"=c(1,2,3,1,1,3))

df2<-data.frame("m1"=c("100010","100010","100010"),"m2"=c("100020","100020","100020"),"week"=c(1,2,3),"freq"=c(3,1,2)) 

print(df1)
      m1     m2 week
1 100010 100020    1
2 100010 100020    2
3 100010 100020    3
4 100020 100010    1
5 100020 100010    1
6 100020 100010    3
print(df2)
      m1     m2 week freq
1 100010 100020    1    3
2 100010 100020    2    1
3 100010 100020    3    2
```

```
df3<- data.frame("m1"=c("100010","100010","100010","100020","100020","100020"),"m2"=c("100020","100020","100020","100010","100010","100010"),"week"=c(1,2,3,1,1,3),"freq"=c(3,1,2,3,3,2))
print(df3)
      m1     m2 week freq
1 100010 100020    1    3
2 100010 100020    2    1
3 100010 100020    3    2
4 100020 100010    1    3
5 100020 100010    1    3
6 100020 100010    3    2
```

I tried separately merge but it created duplicated column for freq which is not desired. Is this anything else I can try?  Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose I would propose two ways of doing this depending on your preference. The first would be using SQL instead of R for the task. It’s a bit more straightforward for the type of join you’re describing.

```r
library(sqldf)
library(dplyr)

df1<-data.frame("m1"=c("100010","100010","100010","100020","100020","100020"),"m2"=c("100020","100020","100020","100010","100010","100010"),"week"=c(1,2,3,1,1,3))
df2<-data.frame("m1"=c("100010","100010","100010"),"m2"=c("100020","100020","100020"),"week"=c(1,2,3),"freq"=c(3,1,2)) 
df3<- data.frame("m1"=c("100010","100010","100010","100020","100020","100020"),"m2"=c("100020","100020","100020","100010","100010","100010"),"week"=c(1,2,3,1,1,3),"freq"=c(3,1,2,3,3,2))

df_sql <- 
  sqldf::sqldf("SELECT a.*, b.freq
               FROM df1 a
               LEFT JOIN df2 b 
               ON (a.week = b.week and a.m1 = b.m1 and a.m2 = b.m2) OR
                  (a.week = b.week and a.m1 = b.m2 and a.m2 = b.m1)")

identical(df_sql, df3)
#> [1] TRUE
```

I am sure there are more elegant ways to do this, but the second strategy is just to duplicate `df2`, rename the columns with `m1` and `m2` reversed, and then do the join.

```r
df <-
  df2 %>%
  rename(m2 = m1, m1 = m2) %>%
  bind_rows(df2, .) %>%
  left_join(df1, ., by = c("week", "m1", "m2"))


identical(df, df3)
#> [1] TRUE
```

I imagine there are other ways that don’t involve a join, but that’s how I would do it using joins.

<sup>Created on 2022-02-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: The sql part works great!

Answer (score 2):

If we want an `OR` join, we could use `regex_left_join` from `fuzzyjoin`

```
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(stringr)
regex_left_join(df1 %>% 
   mutate(m1m2 = str_c(m1, m2, sep = "|")), 
   df2 %>%
    mutate(m1m2 = str_c(m1, m2, sep = "|"), .keep = "unused"), 
     by = c("m1m2", "week")) %>% 
   select(m1, m2, week = week.x, freq)
```

-output

```
      m1     m2 week freq
1 100010 100020    1    3
2 100010 100020    2    1
3 100010 100020    3    2
4 100020 100010    1    3
5 100020 100010    1    3
6 100020 100010    3    2
```

Comment: @ akrun thanks for your help. Can you explain what is >= used here for? Also if the m1 and m2 are character instead of number, is that possible to solve the prolem?

Comment: If it is character, the operator needs to evaluate that is between the range right?

Comment: @ akrun Actually, I may use a wrong word. It is not related to range at all, it is the inclusive. I want to have the m1 and m2 in df1 are same as m1 and m2 in df2. But It doesn't require m1=m1 and m2=m2. So that also means either (m1=m1 & m2=m2) or (m1=m2&m2=m1) satisfies the condition. I hope I explain the question correctly. Thank you.

Comment: @DrexelJ perhaps you need a regex join.  Updated

Comment: Thanks for your update. I checked with my data instead of simple. It created many issues. It created many matchings which doesn't meet the match requirement. It matchs when m1 or m2 in m1m2 in df2 but I need it matchs when not m1 and m2 are both included in m1m2 in df2. I tried to use & instead of |, it provided table only based on m1=m1 and m2=m2 like reguar joining.

Comment: @DrexelJ it is a regex based approach, but looks for the OR match.  If your pattern is different, it wouldn't work